# Get max/min values from a list of dataFrames without loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, max, min

Until now i have just found solutions for getting **the** maximum for a column in several dataframes in a list.

I have stored dataframes `df1, df2, df3, ..., dfn` in a list `dfList` and i want to get the maximum of the column `df_$a` **for each dataframe**. That means e.g. a vector `maxList = c(max_a_df1, max_a_df2, max_a_df3, ... , max_a_dfn)`.

i know that

```
max(dfList[[1]]$a)
```

gives me the maximum value of column `a` of `df1` and i know that i could loop over the `dfList` and add the corresponding maximum to an vecotor.

But maybe there is another way to implement this operation without using a loop?

Comment: `lapply(dfList,function(df)max(df$a))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop through the `list` elements, extract the column 'a' and get the `max` value as a `vector`

```
sapply(dfList, function(x) max(x$a, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Exactly that simple expression i was searching for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @team17  If you need `max/min` then use `range` ie. `sapply(dfList, function(x) range(x$a))`

Comment: thank you for the helpfull tip. Like my question lets out i am new to R and should take a closer look at the basics^^

Comment: @team17 Glad to help you with the question