# Using max in sapply returns warning "No non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"

Tags: r, list, dataframe, max, sapply

**What I want to achieve** 
 Loop through a list of data frames, extract column and calculate max value in that column for each data frame of the list

**What I have done**

- I split a data frame `df` into a list of data frames `df_list` based on values in column `i` (data type: `<chr>`):
  `df_list <- split(df, f = df$i)`
- I used `sapply` as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425562/20470650 to extract column `a` (data type: `<dbl>`) and calculate the `max` value:

  `sapply(df_list, function(x) max(x$a))`

**What I get** 
 This warning message:

`In max(x$a) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`.

There are no `NA` values in column `a`.

I feel like it is a simple problem, but I spent quite some time searching online and reading answers to similar issues, but unfortunately that didn't help me finding out why I get `-Inf` as a return instead of `max` values for column `a` in each df of the list.

Any ideas what could be the reason and how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Substituting in for `x` doesn't work that way in R.  Use this instead:  `max(\`$\`(x, a))` where the single quotes are backticks (usually found near the esc key on the keyboard).

Comment: This case works: `df_list <- split(iris, f = iris$Species); sapply(df_list, function(x) max(x$Petal.Width))`

Comment: run the command `max()`, and you will get the same error. This may be because of null value in particular data frame. I would recommend you to convert column `I` into `character` before splitting the data, and then check the results.

Comment: Is `a` the correct column name?

Comment: This error is about missing values in the column, this is about the whole column does not exist. If you define `df_list = list(data.frame(a = 1),  data.frame(a = NA))` the code works fine. But if you introduce a data frame with no `a` column the error is produced: `df_list = list(data.frame(a = 1), data.frame(a = NA), data.frame(b = 1))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! Column `i` was already in `character` type and I had excluded blank rows. The `max` command works fine when I call individual data frames from the list: `max(df_list[[1]]$a)`.

Comment: Using `max(`$`(x, a)) returns the same warning. The column `a` does exist and the name is correct. Could it be a problem that column `i` was character type?

Comment: what does `df  |> dplyr::group_by(i) |> dplyr::summarize(max = max(a))` return?

Comment: It returns a tibble: 294 x 2 with columns `i` and `max` with the `max` values...so that seems to work.